# Can't pass parameters to find from function execution

Tags: bash, shell, find, command-substitution

I have the need to pass multiple parameters to `find` dynamically. I'm doing that using this function:

```
GEN_FIND_PARAMS() {
    PARAM=""

    for WORD in $1; do
        ADD=""

        if [ X"$PARAM" != "X" ]; then
            ADD="-o"
        fi
        ADD="-name '$WORD' $ADD"

        PARAM="$ADD $PARAM"
    done

    echo $PARAM
}
```

If I run the function by itself, I get correct results:

```
SHD_FILES="*.rev *.db *.cdb"
GEN_FIND_PARAMS "$SHD_FILES"
```

Outputs correctly

```
-name '*.rev' -o -name '*.db' -o -name '*.cdb'
```

However, when I using it fully, it just doesn't find anything:

```
find /dev/shm $(GEN_FIND_PARAMS "$SHD_FILES")
```

Outputs nothing, even though I know the files are there, because running it plainly works:

```
find /dev/shm -name '*.rev' -o -name '*.db' -o -name '*.cdb'
```

Is there something wrong in the value substitution? I'm also open to other ways to do this (there *must* be a better one)

Comment: [How do I store a command in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) Not by putting quotes in it.

Comment: @Gilles I'm puzzled. Putting the quotes as per the linked question explains, the command substitution seems to work correctly, however `find` seems to get it wrong: `find: unknown predicate \`-name '*.rev'` (continues with the other predicates)

Comment: The linked answer explains that you can't do it that way. You're passing the quotes to the `find` command. Read my answer!